# Magento 2 How to import category

Tags: magento2, category, import

anyone have idea about Import categories in M2 or is any module available for import category ?

Comment: Please try this link [click here](https://github.com/navinbhudiya/magento2-import-export-category)

Comment: Thanks but above link not import category store wise.

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya Have you got solution of how to import categories via csv?
I am looking for same. Let me know if you have got solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.